# В какой момент Blazor возвращает Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Имеется вот такой `Razor` компонент, он занимается регистрацией пользователя на сайте:

```
@page "/Register"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager
@using VirtualMachine.Data

<EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    @for (var i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="validation-message">@errors[i].Description</div>
    }
    <InputText class="input" placeholder="login" @bind-Value="user.Login" />
    <InputText type="password" class="input" placeholder="password" @bind-Value="user.Password" />

    <button class="button" type="submit">REGISTER</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private User user = new User();
    private List<IdentityError> errors = new List<IdentityError>();

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        errors = new List<IdentityError>();
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser(user.Login), user.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await signInManager.SignInAsync(new IdentityUser(user.Login), true);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else
            errors = result.Errors.ToList();
    }
}
```

Но когда я произвожу аутентификацию через куки `await signInManager.SignInAsync(new IdentityUser(user.Login), true);` выясняется, что ответ на запрос уже был отправлен, вопрос в том, в какой момент запрос отправляется?

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** "The response cannot be modified bacause the responce has already started."

Comment: я же правильно понимаю, что у вас ServerSide? Я больше в организационных целях интересуюсь, так как считаю, что надо завести отдельные метки для ServerSide и WASM.

Comment: @4per, ну да ServerSide

Comment: Я не особо шарю в теме Identity, но краем глаза глянул доки на методы, которые вы юзаете, и мне кажется что затуп не в коде........... Куки же, как не крути остаются на стороне браузера, даже в ServerSide? Они вообще устанавливаются корректно? а если и да, то может с запозданием? Может воткнуть задержки в ваш код? Описал свои мысли в порядке бреда..не взыщите, если что.